# preg replace find keyword

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

very simple preg replace but I can't think right.

I need to search for keywords such as: `{this_is_a_key}` and replace it with something else.

```
$text = 'this is a sentence with a {this_is_a_key} in it';
echo preg_replace('/\{\w{1}\}/i','keyword',$text);
//output should be
//## "this is a sentence with a keyword in it" ##//
```

so far this doesn't work for me and I have tried a combination of `()` and `[]` but no luck

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could you tell how to replace by regular expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3372735/could-you-tell-how-to-replace-by-regular-expression)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\w{1}` means one "word character". Try `\w+` or `[^\}]+` instead.

Also, when using `\w`, there's no need for the `i` modifier.

Comment: im looking for contstant replacers which i need to use the str_replace instead as explained on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3372735/could-you-tell-how-to-replace-by-regular-expression

Comment: mvds gave pretty good answer. Just use `'{this_is_a_key}'` as keys in the substitution array. That's what he meant by *exercise to the reader.*